# How to deploy 2 separate ASP.NET solutions under one IIS website

Tags: asp.net, iis

I am facing the issue how to deploy 2 separate ASP.NET solutions in one IIS website. This is how I plan to deploy. In the root website folder, I put one solution's published files. Then, I create another folder in that root folder and put another solution's published files.

When I run from IIS, only the contents from root folder works but those inside a folder doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use sub folders (add virtual folder) in IIS.

Remember to set the folders "Convert to Web Application" so it works with dependent configuration context.

Comment: Yes, it works! I created virtual directories in IIS and converted them into applications. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the subfolder as an IIS application in IIS Manager.

Comment: Thanks SLaks! How to set the subfolder? What I do is I create a website from IIS. Then I go to the website directory and create another folder to put my second asp.net published files. Is that correct?